# Vertically center sprite arrow in menu item

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to use a sprite image and a class to mark a particular menu item as having children.  I've got it working, but I don't think I can vertically center the background image.  Also not sure this is the best way to hang an arrow (that changes on hover) to the side of a menu.  I was kinda set on sprites because it'd be my first chance to play with them, and I wanted to do arrows in all cardinal directions for reuse.

```
<nav class="nav">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="justjoelabout.html">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href='#' class="hasChildren"><span>WORK</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="services1"><a href="justjoelprint.html">PRINT</a></li>
                    <li class="services1"><a href="justjoelbranding.html">BRANDING</a></li>
                    <li class="services1"><a href="justjoeleditorial.html">EDITORIAL</a></li>
                    <li class="services1"><a href="justjoelphotography.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="justjoelblog.html">BLOG</a></li>
            <li><a href="justjoelinspired.html">INSPIRED</a></li>
            <li><a href="justjoelcontact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.hasChildren:after {
  content:" ";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/IRDY4zU.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x:0;
  background-position-y:0;
  width: 8px;
  height: 4px;
}

.hasChildren:hover:after {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/IRDY4zU.png");
  background-position-x:0;
  background-position-y:-4px;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yCaU8/)

Comment: remove background-position-x:0; background-position-y:0; and set position:relative then give bottom:...px till meet your need ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `vertical-align`

```
.hasChildren:after{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: This and setting position relative with a bottom worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please replace

```
background-position-x:0;
background-position-y:0;
```

with

```
background-position :0 0;
```

as it is devil's child (MS/IE).

Also this can be set in percentages (not only pixcels), so I strongly suggest testing:

```
background-position :0 50%;
```

Comment: did not realize the x/y were IE things.  Thanks for the education!